# Executing Command Prompt command with python but external matplotlib window does'nt show up

Tags: python, matplotlib, command, command-prompt

when i run a command in command prompt directly, the external matplotlib window pops up, but when i give same command from python script to be executed in command prompt, external matplotlib window does not pop instead it says "Figure 680x900"(dimensions of the figure).i am using window 10

Comment: write plt.show() at end so, it will open in the window

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one it shows y=x line in a window,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```